# How to make kill <tab> show the processes that are shown by ps

Tags: zsh

When I type `kill -9` , it will show me all the processes[zsh: do you wish to see all 119 possibilities (119 lines)?]. A lot of processes from `/System/Library/` which I don't care.

If I just type `ps` directly in shell, it will just show several processes. For example:

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 5872 ttys000    0:00.08 -zsh
 6011 ttys000    0:00.00 ./server
 6014 ttys001    0:00.07 -zsh
```

How can I make this auto-completion show the processes that are only shown by using `ps`?

PS: I am using Mac OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out by myself.

In the `lib/completion.zsh` file,

you can change:

```
if [ "$OSTYPE[0,7]" = "solaris" ]
then
  zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:processes' command "ps -u $USER -o pid,user,comm"
else
  zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:processes' command "ps -u $USER -o pid,user,comm -w -w"
fi
```

to

```
if [ "$OSTYPE[0,7]" = "solaris" ]
then
  zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:processes' command "ps -o pid,user,comm"
else
  zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:processes' command "ps -o pid,user,comm -w -w"
fi
```